# IntelliJ screws up maven project after crash, can't recover

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

So I'm working on my project here

https://github.com/dmg46664/migraine

and everything is fine, until my Toshiba fails to resume from sleep and so I have to hard reboot.

Once rebooted, intellij is now suddenly not happy with the project setup. It was perfectly happy before the reboot. This is not the first time stuff like this has happened. Usually, by clicking on maven->reimport/or deleting and reloading modules etc. (usually I'm not sure what fixes it), I eventually get the project into a useable state.

However, I can spend a fair amount of time trying to do this.

Here are screenshots after the screw up.

[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]
[image: screenshot3]

Everything seems pretty okay from the maven command line. (The html module is expected to fail).

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.0:compile (default) @ migraine-html ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Migraine Metaproject .............................. SUCCESS [0.701s]
[INFO] Migraine Assets ................................... SUCCESS [0.910s]
[INFO] Migraine Core ..................................... SUCCESS [0.620s]
[INFO] Migraine HTML ..................................... FAILURE [1.390s]
[INFO] Migraine Java ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.966s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Sep 08 12:01:13 CAT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/222M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So my question is looking for procedures/workarounds to recover from this.

Comment: Please try `File` | `Invalidate Caches` | `Invalidate and Restart`.

Comment: Yip that solved it! Feel kinda sheepish, but since I've had no need to save all/synchronize etc as it happens automatically, that space on the file menu kind of visually fell off my radar. If you write it as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case editor highlights errors that are not the actual errors in the code and the project still builds, the first thing to try is `File` | `Invalidate Caches` | `Invalidate and Restart`.

Comment: How can I thank you? Thank you very mach you save my day!!